# Trying To Scrape A Spotify Playlist But It Only Gets The First 20 Results Out Of 100

Tags: pandas, selenium, web-scraping, spotify, chrome-web-driver

I was trying to learn selenium and for fun I decided to scrape a Spotify Playlist(hence i didnt use the spotify API for this) but its not obtaining the full list, just the songs that are loaded, I tried the solutions in the web with scrolling and waiting but nothing seems to be working, also tried zooming out and it helps but only finds like 20 30 more results, also when i scroll down manually and try scraping it ignores the first few songs and starts scraping from the part that is loaded. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

website= "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6iwz7yurUKaILuykiyeztu"
path= "C:/Users/ashut/Downloads/Misc Docs/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

service=Service(executable_path=path)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(website) 
containers=driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//div[@data-testid="tracklist-row"]/div[@aria-colindex="2"]/div')

titles = []
artists = []
links = []

for container in containers:
    title=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./a/div').text
    artist=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./span/a').text
    link=container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./span/a').get_attribute("href")
    titles.append(title)
    artists.append(artist)
    links.append(link)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    
mydict={'titles':titles,'artists':artists,'links':links}
artistslist= pd.DataFrame(mydict)
artistslist.to_csv('list_of_artist.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

That page is dynamically loading content based on user's actions, in this case - scrolling and reaching the bottom. So you need to scroll the page to bottom (a few times), until all songs will load and be available in page. You can adapt the following snippet to your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

song_list = []
url='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6iwz7yurUKaILuykiyeztu'
browser.get(url)

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print("accepted cookies")
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button')


bottom_sentinel = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='bottom-sentinel']")))

for x in range(5):
    songs = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='tracklist-row']")))
    for song in songs:
        print(song.text)
        song_list.append(song.text)
    t.sleep(2)
    bottom_sentinel.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
print(list(set(song_list)))
print('Total songs:', len(list(set(song_list))))
```

This will print out quite a few duplicate songs, and at the end a list with unique songs, and the count for unique songs:

```
[...]
Total songs: 105
```

> EDIT

It appears OP is still confused, so I will update this answer with full code (selenium/chrome setup for debian/ubuntu). The following code - **tested on multiple playlists** - will accept the cookies if any cookie popup, scroll the Spotify playlist to the bottom, scrape the songs and will produce a dataframe (saved to a csv file as well) with songs, albums, artists, and links to those.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

song_list = []
df_song_list = []

# url='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6iwz7yurUKaILuykiyeztu' 
# url='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX9u7XXOp0l5L'
url='https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXbITWG1ZJKYt'
browser.get(url)

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print("accepted cookies")
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button')


bottom_sentinel = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='bottom-sentinel']")))

for x in range(7):
    songs = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='tracklist-row']")))
    for song in songs:
        song_list.append(song.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    t.sleep(0.5)
    bottom_sentinel.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    browser.implicitly_wait(15)
for song in list(set(song_list)):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(song, 'html.parser')
    position_in_playlist = soup.select_one('span.VrRwdIZO0sRX1lsWxJBe').text.strip() 
    artist = soup.select_one('span.rq2VQ5mb9SDAFWbBIUIn').text.strip() 
    artist_link = 'https://open.spotify.com/' + soup.select_one('span.rq2VQ5mb9SDAFWbBIUIn').select_one('a').get('href')
    song = soup.select_one('div.t_yrXoUO3qGsJS4Y6iXX').text.strip()
    song_link = 'https://open.spotify.com/' + soup.select_one('a.t_yrXoUO3qGsJS4Y6iXX').get('href')
    album = soup.select_one('span.cPwEdQ').text.strip()
    album_link = 'https://open.spotify.com/' + soup.select_one('div.bfQ2S9bMXr_kJjqEfcwA').select_one('a').get('href')
    df_song_list.append((position_in_playlist, artist, artist_link, song, song_link, album, album_link))
    
print('Total songs:', len(list(set(song_list))))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_song_list, columns = ['Position in Playlist', 'Artist', 'Artist Link', 'Song', 'Song Link', 'Album', 'Album Link'])
df.to_csv('spotty_songs.csv')
df.head()
t.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

This will result in a csv file, and will print out in the terminal:

```
accepted cookies
Total songs: 250
Position in Playlist    Artist  Artist Link Song    Song Link   Album   Album Link
0   226 Sonny Rollins   https://open.spotify.com//artist/1VEzN9lxvG6KPR3QQGsebR He's Younger Than You Are - From "Alfie" Score  https://open.spotify.com//track/11vaRXRIFXJTRr3BuzNbk5  Alfie   https://open.spotify.com//album/5vU75tE3FqpzFnbCXZuRE5
1   145 Phil Woods  https://open.spotify.com//artist/6G4hVmXKJ9NW5JecncK89f In Your Own Sweet Way   https://open.spotify.com//track/3YiuJ3OstUEa93UBqb1vcn  Warm Woods  https://open.spotify.com//album/4lj7s0K81qfLbXdLaDt2Ba
2   10  Ella Fitzgerald https://open.spotify.com//artist/5V0MlUE1Bft0mbLlND7FJz How Long Has This Been Going On?    https://open.spotify.com//track/0HEU3berJ5OBojU8XmEk1c  Ella Sings Gershwin https://open.spotify.com//album/3DJYxksYYP018jgpOTVXqO
3   81  Joe Henderson   https://open.spotify.com//artist/3BG0nwVh3Gc7cuT4XdsLtt Blue Bossa - Remastered https://open.spotify.com//track/6qqK0oeBRapZn8f9hJJENw  Page One    https://open.spotify.com//album/7mQGTuvmdp56DNz0AmMwWi
4   5   Billie Holiday  https://open.spotify.com//artist/1YzCsTRb22dQkh9lghPIrp Blue Moon   https://open.spotify.com//track/1pZn8AX1WulW8IO338hE5D  Solitude    https://open.spotify.com//album/4izD3SCRElbkO06i8yf4Zp
```

Comment: thank you for this but its still only printing 50 songs and that too not from the start but from somewhere in the middle

Comment: Updated my code, now it will get them all 105 songs from that page.

Answer (score 0):

the data is dynamic load,and there maybe multiple artists for one item, I wrote one sample by leverage vscode extension clicknium, for my sample,you can see from [github](https://github.com/automation9417/automation-samples/tree/main/ScrapingSpotifyList)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the answers and everyone who contributed to this, the simplest solution to this that i found was to zoom out the browser to something like 0.1, with the help of `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '0.1'")` other than that u/platipus_on_fire's solution is the one if you do not want to do something like zooming out