# How to capture dynamic table elements while scrolling through table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm currently stuck. The page I am trying to automate is just one large dynamic table. I am attempting to scroll all the way to the bottom to capture all rows before I start working with the data. Currently I have the scroll working, but it is only capturing the row elements in view once it hits the bottom. Using python and selenium.

```
def search_by_item_number(self, itemNumber):
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='dx-texteditor-input' and @aria-describedby='dx-col-1']").send_keys(itemNumber)
    time.sleep(5)
    last_row = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines'][last()]")
    self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', last_row);
    time.sleep(10)
    rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines' or @class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines dx-row-alt']")
   
    item_number_elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@role='gridcell']/a")
    item_numbers = []
    matching_item_numbers =[]
    non_matching_item_numbers = []
    
    for row in rows:
        removed_element = item_number_elements.pop(0)
        item_numbers.append(removed_element.text)

    for item_number in item_numbers:
           if '113' in item_number:
              matching_item_numbers.append(item_number)
    
           else:
              non_matching_item_numbers.append(item_number)
    print(matching_item_numbers)    
    print(non_matching_item_numbers)
```

I'm very new so if anything looks off please let me hear your suggestions.

Comment: What url are you trying to scrape?

Comment: it is one of our test environments at work.

Comment: There is not much I can do, however look at this question/answer about scraping a Spotify playlist: scrolled, grabbed the elems, scrolled again, grabbed again the elems and so on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118931/trying-to-scrape-a-spotify-playlist-but-it-only-gets-the-first-20-results-out-of/73120970#73120970. If that won;t help you, I can show you an example on scraping google image search.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire see below. I'd love to see an example on scraping the google images.

Comment: You can see Google image search scrolling (for another hour or so) at https://ctxt.io/2/AADgQUgTFg . I see you keep trying to scroll with javascript, to the bottom of the page. Did you try to locate an element (within the scrolling element) and scroll to it?

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with the Last_row line. It's selecting the last row in the scrolling table.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Platipus's answer above. I commented out my Last_row and execute_script lines and added his execute script line into my for loop.

```
  def search_by_item_number(self, itemNumber):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='dx-texteditor-input' and @aria-describedby='dx-col-1']").send_keys(itemNumber)
        time.sleep(5)
        #last_row = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines'][last()]")
        #self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', last_row);
        time.sleep(10)
        rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines' or @class='dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines dx-column-lines dx-row-alt']")
       
        item_number_elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@role='gridcell']/a")
        item_numbers = []
        matching_item_numbers =[]
        non_matching_item_numbers = []
        
        for row in rows:
            removed_element = item_number_elements.pop(0)
            item_numbers.append(removed_element.text)
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(2)
    
        for item_number in item_numbers:
               if '113' in item_number:
                  matching_item_numbers.append(item_number)
        
               else:
                  non_matching_item_numbers.append(item_number)
        print(matching_item_numbers)    
        print(non_matching_item_numbers)
```

My Ui did not scroll or end on it's own. However when I manually stopped the running after a while, my print statements printed, and my lists captured the first part of the table, and the end. The elements in the middle were missed.